# RightNow: change the delimiter in SOAP request

Tags: soap, rightnow-crm

I need to change the delimiter for the fields RightNow returns. Currently it returns rows in the following way - field1,field2,field3,etc. I need to be able to change the comma. The code below is working fine, I want to know what is the tag for changing (I tried adding `<ns7:Delimiter>`, it didn't work).

```
          <ns2:Filters xsi:type="n1:AnalyticsReportFilter">

     <ns2:Name>incidents_created_from</ns2:Name>
     <ns2:Operator>
      <v11:ID id="5"></v11:ID>
     </ns2:Operator>
     <ns2:Values>2015-02-11 15:24:00 </ns2:Values>
     <ns2:Attributes>
      <ns2:Editable>true</ns2:Editable>
      <ns2:Required>true</ns2:Required>
     </ns2:Attributes>
     <n2:DataType>
      <v11:ID id="4"></v11:ID>
      <v11:Name>DATETIME</v11:Name>
     </n2:DataType>
     <n2:Prompt>incidents.created</n2:Prompt>
        </ns2:Filters>
       </ns7:AnalyticsReport>
      <ns7:Limit>10</ns7:Limit><ns7:Start>0</ns7:Start>
 </ns7:RunAnalyticsReport>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the Delimiter property to the RunAnalyticsReport.

```
<ns7:Limit>10</ns7:Limit><ns7:Start>0</ns7:Start><ns7:Delimiter>|</ns7:Delimiter>
<ns7:ReturnRawResult>false</ns7:ReturnRawResult><ns7:DisableMTOM>true</ns7:DisableMTOM>
```

(Tested XML generated using C# code.)

If you're running something older than Feb 2012, this parameter isn't available.